# How does C# "this" keyword work to qualify argument in static method?

Tags: c#, wpf, this, richtextbox

I am having problem understanding the argument `this flowDocument doc` in the following method:

```
public static FormattedText GetFormattedText(this FlowDocument doc)
{
    if (doc == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("doc");
    }
    ...
}
```

The caller does **not** specify an argument when calling the above method:

```
myRichTextBox.TextChanged +=
    new TextChangedEventHandler((o, e) => myRichTextBox.Width = 
        myRichTextBox.Document.GetFormattedText().WidthIncludingTrailingWhitespace + 20);
```

I am positive that the method does **not** create `doc` itself.  I have not seen `this` used in this manner before.

Comment: it's an extension method

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`GetFormattedText()` is not a normal method, but an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx).

You can call it like this:

```
 document.GetFormattedText()
```

or this:

```
 ClassName.GetFormattedText(document)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the syntax for an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx), the parameter is the `FlowDocument` object that the method is called on:

```
myRichTextBox.Document.GetFormattedText().WidthIncludingTrailingWhitespace + 20);
                   ^           
                   |
-------------------|
```